# Why `do { ...; exit(...); } while (0)` in C?

Tags: c, function, while-loop, c-preprocessor

As a C newbie I'm having trouble understanding [the following code](https://lwn.net/Articles/543509/):

```
#define errExit(msg)    do { perror(msg); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); \
                           } while (0)
```

I gathered that the reason this function is `#define`d is to override an existing function, but what is the point of a `do ... while(0)` loop with an *unconditional* `exit()` statement? Is it not possible to write this without the loop construct?

Comment: Nice question, I've wondered the same! +1

Comment: Too bad the title duplicate detector didn't pick up this...

Answer (score 9):

Many duplicates here I think.

The `do...while(0)` trick enables you to use `errExit` in various contexts without breaking anything:

```
if(x) errExit(msg);
else return 1;
```

is translated to:

```
if(x) do { ...; ...; } while(0);
else return 1;
```

If you omit the `do...while(0)` part, then you could not reliably add a semicolon for example.

Comment: Why would plain old braces not do the job?

Comment: Nice! +1. That's really clever and tricky.

Comment: Ah, so the whole idea is to keep the resulting code to a single statement as seen from the surrounding code? Neat!

Comment: @Joe Read the complete answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/154138/1488917

Comment: @Joe: No. Because of semicolon. As said by AshRj the answer provided elsewhere is thorough.

Answer (score 2):

Assume the macro didn't have the `do { ... } while(0)` loop, just the 2 statements inside. Now, what if I were to write

```
if( foo() )
    errExit("foo!" );
```

My conditional exit has become a non-conditional exit.

Answer (score 1):

The `do { ... } while(0)` construct is common, and usually considered best practice, for macro functions of multiple statements, such as this. It allows use as a single statement, so there are no surprises.